# lower ac current from speedsensor

Tags: ac

I have replaced my car gearbox with one from a newer model. All works fine except for the speed sensor. The old one had a speed sensor with a toothed wheel and the new one comes with just the sensor. The sensor generates a small ac current. When I'm doing 50mph the cars speedo shows twice as much. I tried several resistors but the voltage remains the same. When the speedo shows 80 (actual speed 40) my multimeter shows around 0.8volt. Can you help me to lower the ac voltage coming from the speed sensor

Comment: The output is most probably the pulses ie frequency : so a simple resistor voltage divider won't cut it... You can try, but I am sure you will need something more involved...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just 1 single resistor youll need a resistive divider: [resistive dividers](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/voltage-dividers/all)

If the input your connecting to isnt high impedance you may also need an opamp in a voltage follower configuration:

https://www.analogictips.com/voltage-follower-unity-gain-amplifier-voltage-divider-faq/

...This is of course assuming that the output voltage is proportional to speed and not something else like frequency

Comment: Thinking about it you would need a DC offset for the voltage follower if needed

Comment: Thank you. I tried the resistive dividers without any luck. What i noticed is that even if i connect whichever side of the speedsensor straight to ground it would not have any effect. I assumed that the speed would show zero when grounded.

Comment: The resistive divider shouldnt be grounding the speed sensor?

Comment: Can you provide a diagram of how youre connecting it?